# Error Date and time odoo v8

Tags: time, odoo-8

When I print my report I always get the time wrong (-1 hour), and I don't know how to solve this problem.

I have this function in my code :

```
def _interpolation_dict(self):
    t = time.localtime() # Actually, the server is always in UTC.
    return {
        'year': time.strftime('%Y', t),
        'month': time.strftime('%m', t),
        'day': time.strftime('%d', t),
        'y': time.strftime('%y', t),
        'doy': time.strftime('%j', t),
        'woy': time.strftime('%W', t),
        'weekday': time.strftime('%w', t),
        'h24': time.strftime('%H', t),
        'h12': time.strftime('%I', t),
        'min': time.strftime('%M', t),
        'sec': time.strftime('%S', t),
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert UTC timezone to User Timezone

You can do it using following method.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

time_zone=self.env.user.tz
if time_zone:
    local_now = datetime.now(pytz.timezone(time_zone))
else:
    local_now=datetime.now()
return {
        'year': local_now.strftime('%Y'),
        'month': local_now.strftime('%m'),
        'day': local_now.strftime('%d'),
        'y': local_now.strftime('%y'),
        'doy': local_now.strftime('%j'),
        'woy': local_now.strftime('%W'),
        'weekday': local_now.strftime('%w'),
        'h24': local_now.strftime('%H'),
        'h12': local_now.strftime('%I'),
        'min': local_now.strftime('%M'),
        'sec': local_now.strftime('%S'),
    }
```

> In above method we have get **UTC time zone using datetime.now()**
>   after that convert **UTC timezone** into **User time zone using pytz
>   function**.

This may help you.